# How to migrate an existing django model to django-ordered-model with Django 1.7 migrations?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have an existing model and I want to make it orderable with `django-ordered-model`, which I chose because it is integrated with `django.contrib.admin`.

Right now the model is ordered by `pk`, and I'd like to preserve that ordering. When I run `manage.py makemigrations` it asks me:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'orderable' to Item without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Both options seem wrong. What should I do?

Comment: Can anyone with enough SO wealth please create and add the tag django-ordered-model?

Answer (score 2):

What I did was answer `1`, provide the value `0`, then in the migration file add:

```
def set_initial_order(apps, schema_editor):
    model = apps.get_model('exercises', 'Item')
    for s in model.objects.all():
        s.order = s.pk
        s.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    # ...
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            # ...
        migrations.AddField(
            # ...
        migrations.RunPython(
            set_initial_order,
            reverse_code=lambda apps, schema_editor: None
        ),
    ]
```

This means the order will initially be 0 for everything, but then immediately will be changed to be equal to `pk`, and in the reverse migration nothing needs to be done because the column is just about to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `order_with_respect_to` setup:

```
def set_initial_order(apps, schema_editor):
    Lecture = apps.get_model('lectures', 'Lecture')
    Item = apps.get_model('exercises', 'Item')
    for lecture in Lecture.objects.all():
        for index, item in enumerate(Item.objects.filter(lecture=lecture).order_by('id').all()):
            item.order = index
            item.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    # ...
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            # ...
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            # ...
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(
            set_initial_order,
            reverse_code=lambda apps, schema_editor: None
        ),
    ]
```